# Asyncio пример сервера

Tags: python, asyncio

Есть такой пример голого сервера на asyncio:

```
import asyncio
import base64
import cgi
import datetime
import io
import json
import logging
import urllib.parse


class JSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
  def default(self, o):
    if isinstance(o, bytes):
      return base64.b64encode(o).decode()
    if isinstance(o, date):
      return o.isoformat()
    return super().default(o)


# Без вызова этого
logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# Это не будет иметь эффекта
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


async def serve(reader, writer):
  addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
  logger.debug('new connection: %s', addr)
  request_line = await reader.readline()
  logger.debug(request_line)
  method, uri, version = request_line.decode().split()
  assert version.startswith('HTTP/')
  version = version[5:].split('.')
  assert len(version) == 2
  version = int(version[0]), int(version[1])
  assert (1, 2) >= version >= (1, 0)
  logger.debug('%s %s %s', method, uri, version)
  headers = {}
  while True:
    header = await reader.readline()
    if header in (b'\n', b'\r\n'):
      break
    key, value = header.decode().split(':', 1)
    headers[key.lower()] = value.strip()
  content_length = int(headers.get('content-length', 0))
  if content_length:
    assert method not in ('GET', 'HEAD')
  content_type, params = cgi.parse_header(headers.get('content-type', ''))
  content = await reader.read(content_length)
  response = {
    'method': method,
    'uri': uri,
    'headers': headers
  }
  if content_type == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
    response['data'] = urllib.parse.parse_qs(
      content.decode(params.get('charset', 'utf-8'))
    )
  elif content_type == 'application/json':
    response['json'] = json.loads(
      content.decode(params.get('charset', 'utf-8'))
    )
  data = json.dumps(
    response,
    ensure_ascii=False,
    indent=2,
    cls=JSONEncoder
  ).encode()
  writer.writelines([
    b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n',
    b'Connection: close\r\n',
    b'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n',
    b'Content-Length: %d\r\n' % (len(data), ),
    b'\r\n',
    data
  ])
  writer.write(data)
  await writer.drain()
  writer.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  coro = asyncio.start_server(serve, '', 5000, loop=loop)
  server =loop.run_until_complete(coro)

  try:
    loop.run_forever()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

  server.close()
  loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
  loop.close()
```

Мне непонятно что я тут делаю неправильно, потому как получаю такую ошибку:

> ```
> DEBUG:__main__:new connection: ('::1', 55684, 0, 0)
> DEBUG:__main__:b'POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n'
> DEBUG:__main__:POST / (1, 1)
> DEBUG:__main__:b''
> ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
> future: <Task finished coro=<serve() done, defined at asyncio_server.py:24> 
>     exception=ValueError('not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)')>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "asyncio_server.py", line 29, in serve
>     method, uri, version = request_line.decode().split()
> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)
> ```

Я же закрыл сокет, но из него все равно происходит чтение?!

Comment: а читалку закрыть?

Comment: > If n is positive, this function try to read `n` bytes, and may return less or equal bytes than requested, but at least one byte.

Надо было всего лишь заменить:

content = await reader.read(content_length)

На:

content = await remote_reader.readexactly(content_length)